# error: incompatible types: ServiceCall<InputStream> cannot be converted

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I am getting this error. Please help me figure out why?

> Error:  incompatible types: `ServiceCall<InputStream>` cannot be converted

```
play.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            new SynthesisTask().execute(reply.getText().toString());
        }
    }
);     

private class SynthesisTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        player.playStream(textService.synthesize(params[0], Voice.EN_LISA));
        return "Did synthesize";
    }
}
```